# Error class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError, original message: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'if'

Tags: yaml

Below condition is failing with above error
abc: "{% if x == 'y' %}1{% else if x == 'z' %}2{% else if z == 'a' %}3{% endif %}"

Comment: Please tag with the templating engine you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's `{% elif ...`, not `{% else if ...`.